# Как правильно подключить jar библиотеку к проекту в Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-sdk

Доброго времени суток.
По каким-то причинам, если мой класс наследует класс, который определен в JAR файле, ClassLoader выбрасывает исключение, что не может найти класс. Однако, если не наследовать класс, то все работает.

Я скопировал проблемную библиотеку **android-support-v4.jar** из android-sdk в **$(PROJECT_PATH)/jars**, затем подключил её в проекте как видно на картинке

[image]

Однако, при старте выбрасывается исключение NotClassFoundError, а перед этим в лог пишется сообщение:

```
> 
> 04-16 23:09:32.131: W/dalvikvm(1571):
> Unable to resolve superclass of
> Lbt/nativeclient/TorrentAdapter; (8)
> 
> 04-16 23:09:32.171: W/dalvikvm(1571):
> Link of class
> 'Lbt/nativeclient/TorrentAdapter;'
> failed
```

Собственно мой код, который наследует класс PagerAdapter из библиотеки:

```
package bt.nativeclient;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.View;
public class TorrentAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    public TorrentAdapter() {

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Я подозреваю, что я не учел какую-то маленькую деталь при работе с eclipse. 
Кто-нибудь может мне помочь с данной проблемой, возможно где-то надо дописать пути?
Спасибо.

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, при работе с jar нужно загружать классы ручками. Вот [презентация о работе с jar](http://www.kgeorgiy.info/courses/java-advanced/slides/jar.pps).

Comment: Add external jars... указываешь путь к файлу и все.. перед этим удали все import в классе, потом передобавь...

Comment: Я делаю так: кидаю в libs, -> Add external jars -> Order and export и ставлю галку!

Answer (score 5):

Начиная с ADT 17 (если я все правильно помню) нужно просто класть в libs, плагин сам добавляет jarку в билдпас, в раздел Android Dependencies, в apk тоже добавляет автоматичекски. Вручную в билдпасе она пробисана быть не должна, если есть - убери.

Если не подтянулась из libs - это глюк. Клин, если не поможет - перезагрузить эклипс, еще раз клин.